# Issues with importing functions of numpy in pycharm

Tags: python, numpy

hey take a look at this code in pycharm.`

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array( [ [1,3],[2,4] ] )
y = np.array([  [2,2],[3,5] ] )
print x*y
print x.dot(y)
```

So both `dot()` and `array()` are numpy function but .
Why can't I just write

```
  x = array( [ [1,3],[2,4] ] )  
  y = array([  [2,2],[3,5] ] )
```

and get rid of "np"..
moreover, when using dot() function , why don't pycharm accepts `x.(np.dot(y))` ??

Comment: `from numpy import array`. You can import everything from `numpy` by doing `from numpy import *` but keep in mind this introduces some namespaces issues (`numpy` might define a global variable somewhere that has the same name of a variable in your own code).

Comment: you could do `from numpy import array` and then just use it as `array` but as @DeepSpace says if anything else uses this exact name you will run into trouble. You can even rename functions upon importing like so: `from numpy import array as bad_programmer` and then use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Pycharm has nothing to do with any of this.

The first issue you raise is the way Python works. You have two options:

- `import numpy`: the function have to be called as `numpy.array()` for example
- `from numpy import array`: the function can be called as `array()`

With the first option you do not run into trouble because `numpy` and every other library is internally consistent meaning the function names are unique.

With the second option there can be issues. For example imagine modules `module_a` and `module_b` both defining `array` and you doing:

```
from module_a import array
from module_b import array
```

What would `array` be in this case? `module_a.array` or `module_b.array`?

---

As far as the second issue is concerned `x.(np.dot(y))`:

This is simply wrong syntax. The matrix (or vector) multiplication with the [`numpy.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) is done like so: `numpy.dot(x, y)`